# How to map a model with reference to a list of another model

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project where I am trying to create one to many relationships using SQL query. I have three models. Where the first model is employed and the second is the department and the third one is documents. At present, I am getting only employee data from the below code. how do I map all the three tables and retrieve data.

```
public class Employee 
{
   public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
   public string Employeename { get; set; }

   public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
   public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Department 
{
   public long DepartmentId { get; set; }
   public string Departmentname { get; set; }
   public long EmployeeId { get; set; 
}
public class Document 
{
   public long DocumentId { get; set; }
   public sting Documentname { get; set; }
   public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
}

       public Employee(long EmployeeId)
    {
        var sqlStatement = @"select * from Employee where EmployeeId = :EmployeeId";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Employee"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmployeeId;
                using (var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Employeename  = reader["Employeename "].ToString();
}

}
```

Comment: When using parameters in sql server + ado.net the parameter names should be prefixed with an at symbol (@) not a colon which is what Oracle uses. So that should be `@EmployeeId`, not `:EmployeeId`. Also `public Employee(long EmployeeId)` is not a valid method signature, you need to always include a name for the method.

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM like EF or Dapper? Then all you are responsible for is mapping your types to your schema and retrieval becomes much more manageable.

Comment: any link for reference would be helpful

Comment: [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

Comment: to converting data tables to objects ORM help you. if you want to use TSQL to retrieve data from db the dapper is the best one.